# How to show one Div when the user hovers over another on Tumblr?

Tags: css, html, tumblr

I'm new to HTML/CSS and I just need some educating on the basics. I have researched how to do what I'm asking but none of the answers on the internet work for my project, I don't know if this is because I'm working on Tumblr or not.

Basically this is the code. I want `#notesbox` to fade in when the mouse hovers over `#post`.
This is the CSS used for the two Div's:

```
    #post{
    position: relative;
    width:250px;
    height: 250px;
    overflow:hidden;
    float:left;
    font-family: "helvetica";
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    }
```

and

```
#notesbox {
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    float: center;
    width: 100%;
    height:20px;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all ease 1s;
    -moz-transition: all ease 1s;
    -o-transition: all ease 1s;
    -ms-transition: all ease 1s;
    transition: all ease 1s;
    }
```

Thankyou for any help and sorry for my ignorance, as I've said I am new so go easy on me!

EDIT: Here is the HTML for it.

```
<center>
<div id = "postholder">
{block:Posts}
<div id="cent">
</div>
<div id="post">

{block:Title}{Title}{/block:Title}

{block:Text}{Body}{/block:Text}

{block:Photo}

<div id = "photo">
<div id = "notesbox">
<div id = "notes">
REBLOGGED FROM
<div id = "reblogged">
{block:RebloggedFrom} {ReblogParentName} {/block:RebloggedFrom}
</div>
</div>
</div>
<a href="{permalink}"><img class = "default" img src="{PhotoURL-500}" width="250"/></a>
</div>
{/block:Photo}
```

The {/block:Post} comes later on in the code.

Comment: can you show your html

Comment: Impossible to help you without seeing the HTML

Comment: I've added the HTML @Coop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said on some comments, your html would help here a lot, but I think I can help you overcome your issue anyway.
My solution uses javascript. There are many stuff you can do with javascript, and it's not that hard to learn, i suggest that if you are building a website you learn it.

On your html, add a "onmouseover" event to #post.

```
 <div id="post" onmouseover="someFunction()"></div>
```

The code above means, when a mouse is over the division (or whatever it is), the function "someFunction()" (that's just a made up name) from the script will be triggered.

this is the script (you can add it in somewhere between your head tags if you don't have many scripts. Usually I use a separate javascript file, but it's not necessary).

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
   function someFunction(){
      document.getElementById("notesbox").style.opacity="0.25";
      document.getElementById("notesbox").style.filter="alpha(opacity=25)";
   }
</script>
```

What it does is, when the function 'someFunction()' is triggered, it searches the document for the element with the 'id' "notesbox" and changes it's css (style) to include "opacity:0.25;"

The second row does the same thing and changes to css to include "filter:alpha(opacity=25);" Both of the rows are needed for the code to work on every browser.

Hope I answered your question. Feel free to ask if something isn't clear.

***EDIT: Answer for your comment.***

There are many divisions with the same 'Id', that makes a problem when working with javascript. The script above, which you have entered, finds the FIRST element with the 'Id' "notesbox" ONLY.
I have 2 solutions for that- one is to change the 'Id's to be different for each division, if you wish "notesbox1", "notesbox2" etc. Then you should have many functions, one for each "notesbox". Each row in the javascript will have to change accordingly:

```
...getElementById("notesbox1")...
```

CSS as well:

```
#notesbox1{}
#notesbox2{}
```

I like the second idea more. The second one uses 'class'es instead of 'id's. Classes are better than divisions when it comes to having the same css/javascript for many elements. This is much more complicated than just using many function for each different division and changing the IDs but it works better and faster. After starting to explain the second idea, I found out that I wrote a lot and didn't even get to the half.  If you have the time and will to learn a little javascript, I'd love to help you out, but before putting so much effort into it, I want to know that you will actually use it.

***EDIT: Idea #2***

I do believe there are easier ways to do it, but as I said in the comment, I'm kind of an amateur myself. Either way, that will teach you a lot.

First, change your division from:

```
<div id="notesbox"></div>
```

To

```
<div class="notesbox"></div>
```

Then, your css, from:

```
#notesbox {}
```

To:

```
.notesbox {} /*  On CSS, the '.' marks a class and the '#' marks an id. */
```

Then your javascript has to be changed as well.
That was the row earlier:

```
 document.getElementById("notesbox").style.opacity="0.25";
```

It has to be changed accordingly to find class insted of an ID.

```
 document.getElementsByClassName("notesbox")[0].style.opacity="0.25";
```

There are a few differences to notice.
when javascript gets a class, the word "Id" has to change to "ClassName".
When javascript gets a class, the word "Element" has to change to "Elements"- This even indicates what I said before: classes are for more than 1 element.
After the '("notesbox") comes a [number], a '0' in the top example. The [0] means that the element chosen will be the FIRST element with the ClassName("notesbox").  Javascript starts counting from 0, not from 1- therefore the second object will be with [1], third with [2] and so on.

After all that is understood, you should make a 'variable' in javascript to get the picture number. The code will make that if you hover over a picture which will be given the number 1, the first element in "notesbox" class will appear (the element ("notesbox")[0])

```
var pic_number;
```

Now make functions.

```
function change_pic_number_1()
{
pic_number=1;
}
```

The above functions, when triggered, changes pic_number to 1. I will assume there are 2 pics only, after you get the hang of it you can add more as needed.

```
function change_pic_number_2()
    {
    pic_number=2;
    }
```

The function that makes the 'notesbox' be shown will use a 'switch' in it. A switch is a method to check a variable's content and act by it. It's close to 'if' but much more useful when there are many options. So:

```
function showNotesBox(){
switch (pic_number){
   case 1:
      document.getElementsByClassName("notesbox")[0].style.opacity="0.25";
      break;
   case 2:
      document.getElementsByClassName("notesbox")[1].style.opacity="0.25";
      break;
}
}
```

the code above means: In 'case' that the var 'pic_number' equals 1, excute the following things until 'break'. In 'case' that the var 'pic_number' equals 2, execute the following things until 'break'. You can see in case 2, the [0] changes to [1].
In the html:

```
<div class="notesbox" onmouseover="change_pic_number_1(); showNotesBox()"></div> //This only makes that when you hover over the notesbox it will be triggered. You need to add the trigger to the photo as well.
```

So what it does is, when you mouse over the division, first the function "change_pic_number_1()" will be triggered, then "showNotesBox()". Go over it your mind, and you'll see that this will change the opacity of the division to '0.25'.

If you understood it already (that's very unlikely) and have done it, you'll encounter a problem in which after you hover over the division, it will stay like that. To encounter that we need another var, switch and function. But first understand the part above.

Again, ask me what you find not clear. You can also read about switch http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp to understand it better. Read what I wrote a couple of times, until you think you understood what you can from it.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! It works, but as you can see on hugowolfdesigns.tumblr.com if you hover over the first picture (the one of The Last Of Us) it does indeed show the notes box (REBLOGGED FROM...) however, if you hover over the over boxes it just shows the box from the first picture and not their respective boxes?

Comment: This is the code I used for the HTML part of the post.

`{block:Photo}

<div id = "photo" onmouseover="FadeInEffect()" onmouseout="FadeOutEffect()">
<div id = "notesbox">
<div id = "notes">
REBLOGGED FROM
<div id = "reblogged">
{block:RebloggedFrom} {ReblogParentName} {/block:RebloggedFrom}
</div>
</div>
</div>
<a href="{permalink}"><img class = "default" img src="{PhotoURL-500}" width="250"/></a>
</div>
{/block:Photo}`

Comment: Thank you for your time, patience and the answer. However, I don't really understand what you mean. So I copy and paste the whole `<div id="notesbox">...</div> 10 times (say if I wanted 10 posts on a page) and change each one to "notesbox1" "notesbox2" etc? Do I then copy and paste #notesbox{(all the CSS rules)} and do the same thing 10 times but again with 1, 2, 3 etc? How do people achieve this effect even with infinite scroll (an infinite amount of posts on a page)?
In regards to your offer I'd absolutely love to learn more about it! Anything to boost my understanding would be great thanks!

Comment: Yes, you should change every division and add the numbers, and add CSS with the numbers and javascript as well. 
I am kind of an amateur myself so I cant answer your question of how people achieve this effect with infinite scroll, but I suppose it's close to my second idea.
I'll edit my answer again and add the second part. It'll take some time :)

Comment: Again, thank you for the time and patience! That was really useful and I do think I understand what you mean. So ("notesbox")[1] tells the computer to change the second notes box. I've used all this code in what I believe to be the right places and it still does not work. It doesn't even effect the first photo anymore if I replace my previous script with this, which is peculiar. I've clearly done something wrong, but just wondering there's only one part I don't fully understand. What is used to activate the functions "change_pic_number"? Thank you! :-)

Comment: As you can see, on the code above I added the row: onmouseover="change_pic_number_1(); showNotesBox()"
this row means that when you mouse over the element, first the change_pic_number_1() function happens, which changes the pic number to 1, then the showNotesBox().
Can you show me the code? On jsfiddle best.

Comment: Here is the code, not very tidy but code none the less! http://jsfiddle.net/EHSrQ/